# Is Delphi available on Visual Studio IDE?

Tags: windows, delphi, ide, programming-languages

I have decided (whether it's for better or for worse), to start learning the Delphi Programming Language. But, Is it available in Visual Studio? Or is there an IDE for it? I googled Delphi, but came up with some really weird sites.

Thanks

Jason

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nobody mentioned [Lazarus](http://www.lazarus.freepascal.org/) which provides an IDE (very like Delphi's) so you can build windows form applications very easily. Like Free Pascal it's free, actually it uses the freepascal compiler

Comment: Perfect. This is all I need while I'm starting out in Delphi! :) Good bye C++ and C# I'll miss you lol

Comment: The combination Lazarus and Free Pascal is about at the level of Delphi 7, some 6 releases of Delphi ago. But for sure a great environment, also because Delphi 7 was one of the best releases.

Comment: I've been using Delphi since 1995, and I have to say that Lazarus trails Delphi a LOT when it comes to polish and completeness. And, of course, the enormous library of freely-available Delphi components may not work well with Lazarus.

That said, Lazarus would certainly be a reasonable place to start, and to get used to the language and techniques.

Answer (score 5):

The official site is: [at this place](http://www.embarcadero.com/products/delphi)

and you can buy Delphi [here](http://shop.embarcadero.com/dr/v2/ec_Main.Entry17c?SID=39696&SP=10024&CID=0&PID=&PN=29&V1=31047844&V2=31047844&CUR=840&DSP=&PGRP=0&ABCODE=&CACHE_ID=419426) for the low low starting price of $899.

You may also want to give [Free Pascal](http://www.freepascal.org/) a try before you go buying stuff. The syntax is almost completely compatible except for it's free and open source. Of course, you don't get a GUI builder and all that, but if you are not sure you want to learn the language, this would be a good way to try it.

Comment: $899!? Hmmm... No wonder people pirate things all the time lol. Oh well, I'll give Delphi a go and download the free trial they have on offer and if I like it I guess I'll just have to start saving! Thanks for your answer.

Comment: When you said "almost completely compatible" did you really mean "almost completely identical", as in "the syntax is pretty much the same"?

Comment: The syntax of the Pascal language itself is the same (though FreePascal does not implement newer language features that recent Delphi versions have introduced).  However, FreePascal does not have Delphi's VCL framework.  Some of Delphi's RTL has been mirrored in FreePascal, and FreePascal's compiler has a Delphi mode for compatibility with some of Delphi's non-standard language features.

Comment: @j-t-s yea what @Remy said. The big thing missing is just the form designer and the other rich IDE features. The actual langugage though is mostly compatible. (about like comparing gcc's C++ and MSVC++s C++)

Comment: Ahh awesome. Thank you for explaining everythnig for me. It's really helped :) I've downloaded FreePascal as well as the Delphi free trial. Will definitly give them both a try :)

Answer (score 5):

To get a real feeling for the Delphi IDE and how to program with Delphi, I'd recommend you view Nick Hodges': [Thirty Camtasia Demos in Thirty Days](http://blogs.embarcadero.com/nickhodges/2006/08/15/26687).

Answer (score 4):

Delphi is a [product](http://www.embarcadero.com/products/delphi) that competes with Visual Studio. If you Google for `Delphi IDE`, the results won't look so weird.

Answer (score 2):

Delphi has it's own environment.  In many respects it's better than Visual Studio, although it's got it's own glitches.

You'll get some strange links with general searches as Delphi is also the name of a company in the car parts business.

Answer (score 1):

Delphi Prism(Delphi for .NET) 2011 will be available for Visual Studio 2010 as a plugin.It's going to be released around holiday 2010.

Comment: It has been available for a while now in previous VS.

Answer (score 1):

Try Delphi Turbo Explorer, it's free and you can use it even for commercial projects:
http://www.video-process.com/turbodelphi_en.exe

Comment: The Turbo editions were discontinued after 2007.  You should not be offering downloads to them from an unofficial website.